# Kendogrid paging parameters not being sent

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am implementing a KendoGrid with server side paging. For some reason, 'pageSize' and 'skip' parameters are not being sent to my remote service. I have serverPaging: true set in the dataSource of the grid. Is there any other setting that is overriding this, making these two parameters unavailable?

Comment: How are we supposed to help you find any errors if you don't provide any code?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your controller action have the **DataSourceRequest** parameter ...

```
public ActionResult yourAction([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
```

and your return like that

```
return Json(yourlist.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```